# Android Studio Vector Asset Import Error - Tags Not Supported

Tags: android, svg, android-studio, vector-graphics

I've been testing out Andorid Studio with the new gradle plugin - 1.4.0-beta3.

I've been trying to import my own vector assets, made in Inkscape. However I keep getting import errors. The error message includes lots of tags in the svg that arn't supported.

```
In mm_card.svg:
ERROR@ line 54 <defs> is not supported
ERROR@ line 56 <linearGradient> is not supported
ERROR@ line 58 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 62 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 66 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 70 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 74 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 78 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 83 <linearGradient> is not supported
ERROR@ line 85 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 89 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 93 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 97 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 102 <linearGradient> is not supported
ERROR@ line 104 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 108 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 113 <linearGradient> is not supported
ERROR@ line 115 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 119 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 123 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 127 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 131 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 135 <stop> is not supported
ERROR@ line 139 <stop> is not supported
```

Does anyone know the cause of this? Is it an error in the vector asset tool? Or perhaps a problem with svgs created by Inkscape? Or are more complicated svgs not supported?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems like pretty basic stuff to not allow. Most SVGs will have a <defs> element, and a large fraction of SVGs will have a linear gradient.

Comment: i had this problem from CorelDraw to Android vector asset importing . then i find the solution : try to convert your SVG exported to vector with this tool : https://shapeshifter.design/  if it's resolved your problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SVG import feature in Android Studio has only limited support for some SVG features.

They state as much in [their announcement video](https://youtu.be/8e3I-PYJNHg?t=2m5s).  They say they intend to improve the importer.

But also note that gradients are not supported in VectorDrawables anyway.

Comment: what is the alternative of <defs>  as the video says copy the vector code and appy certain changes to fix the error.

Comment: They mean copy the path definition.  Which is the value in the `d` attribute of the `<path>` element.

Comment: VectorDrawables don't support gradients but you could use a GradientDrawable as an ImageView background or as part of a LayerDrawable to get the same effect